# Can I use aspects to automagically implement INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: c#, wpf, inotifypropertychanged, postsharp, aspects

Is there a way to use PostSharp to change this kind of code:

```
private _property;
public Object Property
{
    get { return _property; }
    set
    {
        if (_property != value)
        {
            _property = value;
            PropertyChanged("Property");
        }
    }
}
```

into something like:

```
[NotifyChanged]
public Object Property { get; set; }
```

?

Comment: Don't know about PostSharp, but Fody does this nicely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are good instructions here:

http://www.postsharp.net/aspects/examples/inotifypropertychanged

This seems to match up with what you're looking for.